# PdfLatex Xelatex Ascii

Tags: xetex, pdftex, unicode, ascii

I have extracted the following code from the awesome-cv cls:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}


\def\sectionstyle#1#2#3{%
    \textcolor{red}{#1#2#3}%
}

\begin{document}
    \sectionstyle Hello
    \sectionstyle Äabcd
\end{document}
```

The code works with XeLaTex, because it handles the characters internal as UTF-8 symbols. But with PdfLaTex, which still compiles based on ASCII, it does not.

I already thought about using a for loop to detect the UTF-8 octetts, but I don't  know how to make those binary actions in latex / I 've never seen examples/code handling such a problem.

Another idea would be using the stringstrings package, but that sounds quite inefficient and detecting the utf-8 symbols manually would be more interesting.

Maybe you have an idea, how to manage it in pdflatex...

Thanks!

Comment: Of course `\sectionstyle{Ä}{a}{b}cd` would work.

Comment: Yes, but I have wrapped it with another command. So I would have braces nested in braces and I really like to avoid it, because it looks really stupid.

Comment: the supported syntax for _all_ latex commands is to brace arguments. It sometimes works to drop them, but as you see here, generally it does not work. `Ä` is two tokens in pdftex so that takes up `#1 and `#2` of your macro.

Comment: IMHO, `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand*{\sectionstyle}{\textcolor{red}}

\begin{document}
\sectionstyle{Hel}lo
\sectionstyle{Äab}cd
\end{document}` doesn't look stupid given what @MrXeth is apparently trying to do.